# Как проверить введенные данные поля в форме Django

Tags: django, forms

Вступление, в моем проекте есть модель она создает счет для пользователя один из трёх на выбор, задумка заключается в том чтобы пользователь мог создавать три счёта, но чтобы они были разных валют (т.е. счета не повторялись).

```
class Bank_Account (models.Model): # Вторичная модель
account_choices = (
    ('USD', 'USD'),
    ('EUR', 'EUR'),
    ('RUB', 'RUB'),
)
account = models.CharField(choices=account_choices, max_length=7, verbose_name='Счёт')
time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
balans = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Баланс')
client = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Клиент')

def __str__(self):
    return self.account

class Meta: 
    verbose_name = 'Банковские счета'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Банковские счета' 
    ordering = ['time_create']
```

Форма для создания счетов в forms.py:

```
class AddBankAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Bank_Account
    fields = ['account']
```

Функция из views.py

```
def add_account (request):
user = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddBankAccountForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        add_account = form.save(commit=False)
        add_account.client = user
        add_account.save()
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('client_info', args=[user.slug]))
else:
    form = AddBankAccountForm()

return render (request, 'bank/add_account.html', {'menu': menu, 'form': form, 'title': 'Создание счёта'})
```

В функции представления я пытался получить данные пользователя который делает запрос на создание счёта и после отправки формы пользователем проверять если у него уже такой созданный счет, вот так это выглядело

```
def add_account (request):
user = request.user
accounts_user = user.bank_account_set.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddBankAccountForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        add_account = form.save(commit=False)
        add_account.client = user
        if add_account.account in accounts_user:
            return redirect('list_clients')
        add_account.save()
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('client_info', args=[user.slug]))
else:
    form = AddBankAccountForm()

return render (request, 'bank/add_account.html', {'menu': menu, 'form': form,  'title': 'Создание счёта'})
```

Но из этого ничего не вышло, также находил информацию по валидации полей с помощью метода clean_fieldname(), но он прописывается в файле forms.py в нем я не смогу получить доступ к пользователю который обращается к форме. Т.е. я так понимаю проверку поля мне нужно все таки прописывать в функции представления.
Подскажите как сделать чтобы пользователь не мог создавать повторяющиеся счёта, возможно можно как то сделать чтобы они вообще пропадали из поля для выбора или если такой счёт у пользователя уже создан то форма выдавала ошибку. Можно просто указать направления куда капать или ссылку на статьи , буду рад любой подсказке. Извиняюсь, что так длинно ))

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом.

Форма для создания счетов в forms.py:

```
class AddBankAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(AddBankAccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_account(self):
    form_account = self.cleaned_data.get('account')
    existing = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user, account=form_account).exists()
    if existing:
        raise ValidationError('Такой счёт уже существует')
        
    return form_account

class Meta:
    model = Bank_Account
    fields = ['account']
```

Функция представления из views.py

```
def add_account (request):
user = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddBankAccountForm(request.POST, user = request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        add_account = form.save(commit=False)
        add_account.client = user
        add_account.save()
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('client_info', args=[user.slug]))
else:
    form = AddBankAccountForm()

return render (request, 'bank/add_account.html', {'menu': menu, 'form': form, 'title': 'Создание счёта'})
```